# Laravel 5.1 configuration issue

Tags: laravel

getting trouble with laravel

when i hitting url to the browser it shows up to me directory that should not be happend i don't know how to fix it.

```
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -    
[DIR]   css/    2016-04-03 19:40    -    
[DIR]   doc/    2016-04-03 19:38    -    
[IMG]   favicon.ico 2016-04-03 19:37    1.1K     
[DIR]   img/    2016-04-03 19:45    -    
[DIR]   js/
```

Please suggest

Comment: Did you point your web server to a `public` directory or to Laravel project root directory? What webserver do you use (Apache/nginx)? DId you change anything in `.htaccess` file?

Comment: may be you have no index.php file in your public folder.

Comment: we are using apache and there is not .htaccess file instead uploading it does not show

Comment: Do you have a `index.php` file in there?

Comment: Also, you should bring in the `.htaccess` file https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/public/.htaccess

Comment: No index file into route file but it is in public folder

Comment: It seems like you have overwritten the `public` folder contents.